# Delete all files except a few using bash command

Tags: linux, bash, file-management, rm

I have a directory containing lot of files in different formats. I would like to know how I can delete all files with specific format (Lets say *.dat) except a few files in a same format (e.g. A.dat and B.dat). Please advise!

Comment: What did you try? and how did you fail?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/214410/13792

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd write a little script (as a command-line one-liner it is slightly too big):

```
#!/bin/sh
for f in *.dat; do
   case $f in
      (A.dat|B.dat)
         ;;           # do nothing
      (*)
         rm -- "$f";; # remove the file
   esac
done
```

As an alternative, you could use an interactive `rm -i *.dat` which asks you for each file if it should be removed. Answer `y` for the files you no longer need, and `n` for `A.dat` and `B.dat`.

Modern shells like zsh and bash also offer powerful globbing features for your problem. I suggest you read their manual pages, which will help you become a proficient shell guru.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that works to me but I'm wondering if there is any one-line script that can do the same preferably !!